# I want to make a desktop application to see the location of Omegle user's appearing on my screen how to do?

Tags: desktop-application, desktop

I want to make a desktop application to see the location of Omegle users appearing on my screen. I Don't know how to make it, which software or language to use. Your help would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I have the code to find the location of the people appearing on my screen I just want to create a small app visible on the desktop that show's the location continuously and refreshes automatically